# How can you use a single quote in an applications name for Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to use an application name like:

```
#define MyAppName "That's all folks"
```

But #include "modpath.iss" is not compiling out because of the single quote.  If I make it That''s all folks, it does work, strangely enough.

Comment: What is that modpath.iss and what is the error that you get when compiling ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found your answer [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).

It says you need to use `{%hex}` syntax. `hex` is the hex value of the character you want to escape, which is 25 in your case. So you need to use:

```
 #define MyAppName "That{%25}s all folks"
```

I tried it, and it works. Just make sure to update your exe name everywhere if it's in other places in your script.

Comment: Where does the help say this ? Those hex escapes are described only for certain constants. And constants are not involved here. The question is about the `AppName` directive (I presume), and preprocessor. Also, the notation you showed is wrong. There are no curly braces. It would be just `That%25s all folks`.

Comment: @purplehuman For me, that only add's the %25s to the program name, directory name, etc.  It doesn't seem to be escaping at all

Comment: I updated my answer. I think `'` is a constant after all. It can't be escaped otherwise.